# Has android 4.3 added new filesystem security of some kind?

Tags: android, security

I've noticed a couple of things on my new Nexus 7 with android 4.3:

I can't read the *apk.gz files Titanium Backup creates in its backup directory (I wanted to copy the backup dir to my host computer). I get permission denied, but "ls -l" shows all the files as -rw-rw-r- access. Even if I su to root, I can't read them.

I was using rsync to copy some files from my host computer to the Nexus 7, and rsync gets errors trying to set the time on the files to make them the same time as the source files (it does copy the files though, so it had access to do that).

This all seems like it might be some new security features (some kind of new ACL maybe), but I haven't been able to find any hint of what is actually going on here. Does anyone know?

Comment: Can you set the rights to 777? Or mabey chown to an other user?

Comment: Ah by the way this remembers me of a problem i had myself. I had a /sdcard/folder what i coudn't remove. After a long time i found out that when i used 'rm /mount/sdcard/folder' i could remove it without problems. Mabey you have the same problem?

Comment: Where is "its backup directory"?

Comment: That's actually kind of interesting. When it first installed, I could swear it was /storage/emulated/legacy/TitaniumBackup, but just checking now (there have been a couple of updates since the initial install) I see it says /storage/emulated/0/TitaniumBackup (but I still can't read the .apk.gz files).

Comment: And I just did a "mount" command and see that /storage/emulated/0 is a fuse filesystem of some kind, so I supposed android could be doing anything it feels like with security and restrictions inside whatever fuse code is running regardless of the info reported by ls -l.

Comment: Sounds like selinux...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. For device usage questions, try android.stackexchange.com.